# Redirect Laravel когда товар внизу списка

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет. Делаю тестовый инет магазин, когда кто то добавляет товар в корзину я поставил
`return redirect()->back();`

Если товар вверху списка, то проблем нет, а вот если товар находится внизу, то при перезагрузке страницы выкидывает наверх. Не очень удобно. Делать редирект на корзину как то тоже не то. Какие есть еще способы реализации этого?

Якорь может ставить? С редиректом получится?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Например юзать ajax?

Comment: Да, как вариант, но интересно было, вдруг есть варианты без него.
Еще как вариант `return redirect('basket');`, а в ссылке поставить `target="_blank"`, тогда новой вкладкой перекинет на корзину, а текущая останется на том же месте. Но все же, что то не то)

Comment: Ну самый извращённый это сделать каждому товару анкор типа `product-{PRODUCT_ID}`, и делать редирект по типу `return Redirect::to(URL::previous() . "#product-".$product->id);`

Answer (score 0):

Корзина товаров и товары, это уже по сути разные вещи и грубо говоря разные массивы. Из этого следует, что вы можете [к первому массиву корзины прибавить второй массив товаров](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php).

Н ясен сам вопрос, если нужно вывести товары с приоритетом вверху списка, но при этом сама корзина не учитывается в БД, то пишите товары в сессию и из сессии фильтруйте товар для выдачи на показ.

Comment: При добавлении корзины обычным методом после нажатия кнопки "Добавить в корзину" страница сайта перегружается и пользователь оказывается вверху сайта. А если товаров много, то это неудобно. Я все же решил через ajax делать, но тогда не хотелось. Способ решения помогли найти, с помощью JS запоминать позицию скролла и при нажатии кнопки "Добавить в корзину", эта позиция возвращалась и пользователь оказывался на том товаре, который он добавил в корзину.
Вот тут @InDevX подсказал как это реализовать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1205958