# Сохранение позиции скролла при нажатии кнопки и перезагрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Я уже задавал похожий вопрос, но попробую перефразировать. Есть магазин, добавление в корзину сделал на обычном php(Laravel). При добавлении в корзину срабатывает submit (хотя там не `<button>`, а обычная ссылка `<a>`) и страница перезагружается. И хотелось бы, чтобы при нажатии добавить в корзину, пользователя перенесло к тому продукту, на кнопку которого он нажал, а не в начало страницы. Может например добавить кнопке id, а через JQuery отправлять к ней? Возможно у самого php есть такая возможность? Знаю про AJAX, но уже здесь корзину переделывать не хочется.

P.S. Видел вариант сохранения скролла при любой перезагрузке, но даже если пользователь вышел с сайта, а через время зашел, либо сам перезагрузил страницу, позиция скролла сохранится, а это не то, хотелось бы чтобы это срабатывало только после нажатия кнопки.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Лучший вариант - ajax. Так как вы хотите - можно сохранять позицию скролла, к примеру, в local storage, и после перезагрузки смотреть storage, скроллить куда записано и удалять записанную позицию чтобы больше не было скроллов.

Comment: `let cords = ['scrollX','scrollY'];
window.addEventListener('unload', e => cords.forEach(cord => localStorage[cord] = window[cord]));
window.scroll(...cords.map(cord => localStorage[cord]));`

Для сохранения позиции скролла нашел такой код, опыта в JS не много, что добавить, чтобы удалить записанную позицию? И можно ли сделать, чтобы она удалялась сразу после перезагрузки страницы (вернула пользователя куда надо и удалилась)?

Comment: Всё можно. Чтобы добавьте - `cords.forEach(cord => localStorage.removeItem(cord));` после window.scroll.

Comment: Получится вот так?
`let cords = ['scrollX','scrollY'];
window.addEventListener('unload', e => cords.forEach(cord => localStorage[cord] = window[cord]));
window.scroll(...cords.forEach(cord => localStorage.removeItem(cord));`

P.S.3 точки перед `cord` какую функцию выполняют?

Comment: Можно, по сути, и не удалять т.к. скролл к 0 и так в нужном месте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let cords = ['scrollX','scrollY']; 
// сохраняем позицию скролла в localStorage
window.addEventListener('unload', e => cords.forEach(cord => localStorage[cord] = window[cord])); 
// вешаем событие на загрузку (ресурсов) страницы
window.addEventListener('load', e => {
    // если в localStorage имеются данные
    if (localStorage[cords[0]]) {
        // скроллим к сохраненным координатам
        window.scroll(...cords.map(cord => localStorage[cord]));
        // удаляем данные с localStorage
        cords.forEach(cord => localStorage.removeItem(cord));
    }
});
```

*UPD.* *Если у каждого товара есть для перехода эл-т, то вешаем событие на него*:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.cardButton').forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', () => {
        cords.forEach(cord => localStorage[cord] = window[cord]); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо! Но вот единственное непонятное. Если я вручную прокручу в самый низ страницу и потом вручную по url перейду на другую страницу, то скролл сохранится, это можно пофиксить?

Comment: А, точно, я же не сказал. Делаю на Laravel. После события AddToCart у меня срабатывает return redirect()->back(); То есть пользователь после добавления остается на той же странице, на которой и был. Для этого я хотел сохранить позицию скролла. А вот если например с этим скриптом любую страницу пролистать вниз и к примеру вручную прописать ulr другой страницы (контакты к примеру) то скролл останется, контакты откроются со скроллом внизу страницы, но это не критично, вряд ли пользователь будет вручную прописывать url страниц.

Comment: Все, теперь разобрался, большое спасибо!
Единственное спрошу, лучше повесить на конкретную кнопку или в целом все клики отслеживать? Можно ведь так :
`window.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click', e => cords.forEach(cord => localStorage[cord] = window[cord]));`
Но с конкретной кнопкой что то не хочет работать.
Или же лучше просто :
`window.addEventListener('click', e => cords.forEach(cord => localStorage[cord] = window[cord]));`
Второй вариант работает нормально, но отслеживать все клики наверное не стоит?

Comment: Предпочтительней первый вариант, только `document.getElementBy...` Или у вас у каждого товара есть кнопка эта?

Comment: Да, "Добавить в корзину" на каждом товаре. На главной странице есть карусель "Лидеры продаж", там у каждого товара есть эта кнопка, в каталоге, в определенной категории так же. Только если открыть конкретный товар, он там один с этой кнопкой будет.
А то что сначала я document.getElementBy, а потом window.addEventListener('load'...
Никак конфликтовать не будет(то есть document с window)?

Comment: Обновил ответ. К слову, если на странице больше одной кнопки - id один и тот же задавать нельзя, можно класс добавить, к примеру, и по нему искать

Comment: Так, но, повторюсь - больше одного эл-та с id нельзя на страницу ставить, это не правильно, и когда выбирать эти эл-ты по id всегда будет "браться" только первый найденный, потому что id должен быть уникален. Потому и надо добавлять class или другой атрибут, в таких случаях

Comment: Да, все работает, большое спасибо!). querySelectorAll('.cardButton'), надеюсь этому классу не будет мешать то, что там рядом еще куча классов этого элемента)
Кстати, еще не работало из-за того, что одна лишняя круглая скобка после `windows[cord]`(в нижнем коде).

Comment: Опечатка, извиняюсь. Наличие других классов никак не будет влиять.

Comment: Мне `google` подсказывает, что еще `selectorAll` нужно исправить на `querySelectorAll` (вдруг еще кто то на этот вопрос наткнется, чтобы долго не искал в чем проблема).

Comment: Правильно подсказывает. Что за день...