# Как написать такую же функцию, но для одного элемента чистый JS

Tags: javascript

Пару дней как перестал использовать jQuery, решил изучить найтивный JS, пытаюсь разобраться в некоторых вопросах.

Несколько месяцев назад, пользователь @InDevX помог написать такую функцию, которая после клика и перезагрузки страницы возвращает пользователя на то место, где клик произошел или другими словами сохраняет позицию скролла. [Вот этот ответ.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1205958/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B)

Меня интересует следующее, как переписать ее для случая, если у меня только один элемент с таким классом. Здесь же возвращается массив с элементами этого класса. Я понимаю что это и для одного элемента будет работать, но все же, как ее переписать чисто для 1 элемента?

```
let cords = ['scrollX','scrollY'];
document.querySelectorAll('.scrollOffset').forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', () => {
        cords.forEach(cord => localStorage[cord] = window[cord]);
    });
});
// вешаем событие на загрузку (ресурсов) страницы
window.addEventListener('load', e => {
    // если в localStorage имеются данные
    if (localStorage[cords[0]]) {
        // скроллим к сохраненным координатам
        window.scroll(...cords.map(cord => localStorage[cord]));
        // удаляем данные с localStorage
        cords.forEach(cord => localStorage.removeItem(cord));
  }
});
```

Comment: заменяете `querySelectorAll` на `querySelector` и вместо цикла сразу ставите в цепочку `addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

```
let cords = ['scrollX','scrollY'];
document.querySelector('.scrollOffset').addEventListener('click', () => {
   cords.forEach(cord => localStorage[cord] = window[cord]);
});
```